# Spring Integration expression too slow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a problem with Spring Integration.
I have a filter with this expression:

```
<int:filter input-channel="inputTaskChannel" expression="!headers[auditTask].empty and headers[Task].get(0).equals('N') and headers[sendTask].equals('N')" discard-channel="taskErrorChannel" output-channel="sendTaskChannel"/>
```

My problem is that the expression took 750 ms to evaluate the expression. This is a lot of time i think for evaluate an expression. Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you measure the time taken by the evaluation of the expression? Do you compare with a simpler expression or with a filter bean?

Comment: Also just in case, you could send many messages to this filter and check if the evaluation time is the same for all messages, or if it is just high for the first message.

Comment: @Alban. I put a time Stamp before and after.
I send 10, 100, 1000 messages and the time is always the same, more or less 750ms.

Comment: Which spring version are you using? If you are using a newer version you can compile the expression which should make it faster. But evaluating expressions is generally slow compared to a plain method call. There is EL parsing en calls using reflection all those add to the time it takes to execute.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could provide the average processing time when using a plain method call instead.

Comment: @M. Deinum. We are using spring 4. ¿How can i do the precompile of the expression?

Comment: See [the SpEL documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-spel-compilation) `-Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=mixed` (requires Spring Framework 4.1).